# How to iterate over two lists without using nested for loops?

Tags: python, list, algorithm

If a and b are two lists then how can we get c without using nested for loops in python?

```
a=[1,2,3] 
b=[4,5,6] 
c=[(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6)]
```

Let's assume I have to find the sum of all nth term of fibonacci sequence formed by these pairs as the first two numbers, where n is any positive number. 
In this case for n=3 answer in 63.

```
>     1 4 5 nth term in 5  1 5 6 nth term in 6  . . . 3 6 9 nth term in 9 
>            > Sum of all nth term in 63.
```

Comment: What does this have to do with time complexity?

Comment: what if the length of list is something around 10^6? then the nested loop will not be efficient.

Comment: @Anonymous Efficiency is not the same as fast; if you want a list of 10^6 items, it's going to take as long as it takes to generate it.

Comment: @Anonymous If lists `a` and `b` have around 10^6 elements, then you don't have enough memory for `c`. OTOH, if `c` has around 10^6 elements, then any algorithm that generates `c` will have a running time proportional to 10^6.

Comment: @Anonymous The edit completely changes the question. It's considered bad etiquette here on SO to change a question in a way that invalidates existing answers. I suggest that you undo the edit, accept one of the answers, and then start a new question. You're more likely to get help that way.

Comment: If you want to produce every possible pair, i.e. the cartesian product, then you have no choice. You've now changed your question, which is totally different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `product` method from `itertools` package.

```
a=[1,2,3] 
b=[4,5,6]
c = list(itertools.product(a,b))
print(c)
```

Output

```
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: @Anonymous and yet it isn't, like you asked.

Comment: `itertools.product` itself runs in O(1) time; the elements of the product are produced as you iterate over the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

zip(np.repeat(a, 3), np.tile(b, 3))

# [(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: `list(zip(...))` on python3.